# How to add new jobs in ultimate cron in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, cron, drupal-modules

I am new with drupal. I have installed `ultimate cron` in Drupal 7. now I have created a php script to be a `mycron.php`, my problem is that I don't know where can I insert my cron job in my Drupal's `ultimate cron`.

I am looking where can I insert `mycron.php` to `ultimate cron module page` but I failed.

I also look to the site where i downloaded it but it is not there. http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't add custom cron scripts (full .php files) but defining the job that needs to be done using [hook_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7)

If you create a module with "myname" as the name and you can now define a function like

```
function myname_cron(){
//do stuff here
}
```

You can use full Drupal functions here as a fully boostrapped Drupal instance available for you. and Ultimate Cron (or other cron-related modules) can take care of load balancing now.

Comment: Don't forget to `Discover jobs` under _admin/config/system/cron/jobs_ after you defined your new job.